# How to prevent unban in fail2ban?

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

After configuring a port 22 forward from my router to my raspberry pi, I found that there were a TON of IPs trying to get in daily. I have tried to make my system more secure by setting up `ufw` and `fail2ban`.

In `fail2ban`, I have configured it to indefinitely ban IPs which have failed to log into the raspberry for 3 times. I do this by adding the following lines into `/etc/fail2ban/fail.local` :

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

However, I found that when I run the following command in my terminal:

```
zgrep -a "Unban" /var/log/fail2ban.log*
```

I still see a whole lot of IPs which are being unbanned.

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz:2020-04-03 15:40:37,096 fail2ban.actions        [503]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban <IP here>
/var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz:2020-04-04 02:28:23,485 fail2ban.actions        [503]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban <IP here>
/var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz:2020-04-04 23:51:52,909 fail2ban.actions        [503]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban <IP here>
```

---

What is the difference between `ssh` and `sshd`? how do I prevent all unbans?

Answer (score 3):

A ban is always temporary  , because mistake , ip are allocated in dynamic manner .

So i recommend to you :

***1) modify the bantime***

This command will extract the current configuration of sshd jail

```
fail2ban-client -d --dp   | grep -e 'sshd'  | grep -E '(maxretry|findtime|bantime)'
```

so you can add :

```
[sshd] 
bantime = 3600
```

in you file `fail.local` so each time it will ban for  1 hour instead of 10 min for the default  .

i will keep this bantime small, in case you do a mistake , when you are remote and try to access to your server .

***2) activate recidive***

**BUT** you can **ACTIVATE** the **recidive** jail . The recidive jail will catch  ip that was ban multiple times and ban longer .

```
[recidive]
enabled = true
maxretry = 4
bantime = 1w
findtime = 1d
```

and with these setting , after 4 x 3 tries in the last day , a bad IP will be ban 1 week

Comment: Recidive is definitely the way to go +1

Comment: I have recidive enabled and it bans ip's, but the original jail then still decides to unban that ip that recidive (and it)  banned  a few mins later.

Answer (score 1):

Add bantime to your jail like this -

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 3600
```

It will each IP after 3 failed attempts for 1 hour, not indefinitely. You could easily tweak this by changing the bantime. Plus, you'd also want to activate **recidive**

Comment: Could you explain why changing the log matters?